# Error deserializing simple inheritance model with protobuf

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

There appears to be a problem when the empty constructor for an object creates an instance for one of its properties and passes itself as an argument. Specifically when that instance is of a derived type and the property will be deserialized to a different derived type.

I encountered this issue in my application and extracted a unit test that demonstrates it:

```
public class ProtobufStackOverflowTest
{
    [ProtoContract]
    private class Node
    {
        public Node()
        {
            Composition = new VComposition(this);
        }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public Composition Composition { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(10, typeof(GComposition))]
    [ProtoInclude(11, typeof(VComposition))]
    private abstract class Composition
    {
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    private class GComposition : Composition
    {
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    private class VComposition : Composition
    {
        public VComposition()
        {
        }

        public VComposition(Node node)
        {
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    private class Model
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public Node Source { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Testthing()
    {
        var model = new Model();
        var sourceNode = new Node();
        var sourceComposition = new VComposition();

        sourceNode.Composition = sourceComposition;
        model.Source = sourceNode;

        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => GetSerializedCopy(model));
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] buffer)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
        }
    }

    public static T GetSerializedCopy<T>(T obj) { return Deserialize<T>(Serialize(obj)); }
}
```

When run this gives the result of:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in protobuf-net.dll

What I can see of the call stack consists entirely of the following block repeated:

```
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) + 0x51 bytes 
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(int key, object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) + 0x1fe bytes   
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoBuf.ProtoReader reader, System.Type type, object value, bool noAutoCreate) + 0xa5 bytes   
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source, object value, System.Type type, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) + 0xd7 bytes   
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source, object value, System.Type type) + 0x4f bytes  
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.Merge(ProtoBuf.ProtoReader parent, object from, object to) + 0x19a bytes  
[Lightweight Function]  
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read(object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) + 0x51 bytes 
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(int key, object value, ProtoBuf.ProtoReader source) + 0x1fe bytes   
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoBuf.ProtoReader reader, System.Type type, object value, bool noAutoCreate) + 0xa5 bytes   
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source, object value, System.Type type, ProtoBuf.SerializationContext context) + 0xd7 bytes   
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream source, object value, System.Type type) + 0x4f bytes  
protobuf-net.dll!ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.Merge(ProtoBuf.ProtoReader parent, object from, object to) + 0x19a bytes  
[Lightweight Function]
```

This occurs using version 2.0.0.640 of protobuf-net

Any info on what is causing this to happen would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the release v2.1.0-alpha-1 fixes this.

https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/releases

Regards,

Pluc